# getView is not called

Tags: java, android, xml, listview, adapter

Hi all i have problemm that getView() is not called. Sup please. And in project i am using ViewPager. So maybe it's becouse of that

Here my MainActivity

```
package com.uinleader.animewatcher;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ListView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private List<View> pages;
    private View recent;
    private View top_seven;

    private ViewPager mPager;
    private final ArrayList<Parsed> info = new ArrayList<Parsed>();
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        initUi();
        LVInit();

    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        //getMenuInflater().inflate(android.R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    private void initUi() {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
        pages = new ArrayList<View>();

        recent = inflater.inflate(R.layout.recent, null);
        recent.setTag(getString(R.string.recent));

        top_seven = inflater.inflate(R.layout.top_seven, null);
        top_seven.setTag(getString(R.string.top));

        pages.add(recent);
        pages.add(top_seven);

        PAdapter adapter = new PAdapter(pages);
        mPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        mPager.setAdapter(adapter);
        mPager.setCurrentItem(0);


    }
    private void LVInit() {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
        Parsed one = new Parsed("One", "1", R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        Parsed two = new Parsed("Two", "2", R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        Parsed three = new Parsed("Three", "3", R.drawable.ic_launcher);

        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.top_seven, null);

        info.add(one);
        info.add(two);
        info.add(three);
        ListView lv = (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        MArrayAdapter radapter = new MArrayAdapter(MainActivity.this, R.id.listView1, info);
        lv.setAdapter(radapter);
    }
}
```

Here is adapter

```
package com.uinleader.animewatcher;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * Created by uinleader on 28.09.13.
 */
public class MArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Parsed> {

    private final Activity activity;
    private final ArrayList<Parsed> items;
    public MArrayAdapter(Activity a, int textViewResourceId, ArrayList<Parsed> items) {
        super(a, textViewResourceId, items);
        activity = a;
        this.items = items;
        Log.e("ListViewDebug", "Inside Adapter");
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        Log.e("ListViewDebug", "Start Function");
        View view = convertView;
        ViewHolder holder;
        if (view == null) {
            Log.e("ListViewDebug", "In First IF");
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_layout, parent, false);
            holder = new ViewHolder();


 holder.title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.anime_title);
        holder.ep_num = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.ep_number);
        holder.ep_preview = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.ep_preview);
        view.setTag(holder);
    }else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
    }

    Parsed item = items.get(position);
    if(item!=null) {
        holder.title.setText(item.anime_title);
        holder.ep_num.setText("Episode: "+item.ep_num);
        holder.ep_preview.setImageResource(item.img);
    }

    return view;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return items.size();
}

private static class ViewHolder {
    public TextView title;
    public TextView ep_num;
    public ImageView ep_preview;
}
```

}

Here is my class for data. And XML's

```
package com.uinleader.animewatcher;

/**
 * Created by uinleader on 28.09.13.
 */
public class Parsed {
    public String anime_title;
    public String ep_num;
    public int img;

    public Parsed (String anime_title, String ep_num, int img ){
        this.anime_title = anime_title;
        this.ep_num = ep_num;
        this.img = img;
    }
}
```

XML for list.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView1"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent">
    </ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

XML for row's

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >




        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="200px"
            android:layout_height="200px"
            android:id="@+id/ep_preview"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/anime_title"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/ep_preview" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/ep_number"
        android:layout_below="@+id/anime_title"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/ep_preview" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); already "inflates" the current layout the activity is using..i don't why you are inflating other stuff in the "init" methods, that is probably why nothing is being called because the activity remains displaying the view set on R.layout.activity_main.

Comment: Really thanks man :) Only learning android... When readed your message more good understanded all :)

Answer (score 0):

**ArrayAdapter** works a bit differently than **BaseAdapter** - which is for what you're implementing your getView

I suggest several options to fix :

1. change your `ArrayAdapter` to `BaseAdapter`
2. or use the built in ArrayList that comes with the ArrayList adapter
   in your constructor write the following :

   ```
   public MArrayAdapter(Activity a, int textViewResourceId, ArrayList<Parsed> items) {
       super(a, textViewResourceId, items); //<== call to super instantiates the items
       activity = a;
       //ArrayListAdapter has a built in arrayList - use it
       Log.e("ListViewDebug", "Inside Adapter");
   }
   ```

change your getView to this:

```
 @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        Log.e("ListViewDebug", "Start Function");
        View view = convertView; // **note why do you allocate again? just write convertview everywhere  instead of view**
        ViewHolder holder;
        if (view == null) {
            Log.e("ListViewDebug", "In First IF");
                      //**I recommend instantiating the inflater once inside the constructor**
            LayoutInflater inflater =   
                     (LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_layout, parent, false);
            holder = new ViewHolder();


        holder.title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.anime_title);
        holder.ep_num = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.ep_number);
        holder.ep_preview = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.ep_preview);
        view.setTag(holder);
    }else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
    }

    Parsed item = (Parsed)getItem(position); //<==== this
    if(item!=null) {
        holder.title.setText(item.anime_title);
        holder.ep_num.setText("Episode: "+item.ep_num);
        holder.ep_preview.setImageResource(item.img);
    }

    return 

view;
}
```